# Removing a CSS onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make my link toggle from left to right. I'm using the code below;

### HTML:

```
$forum_threads = '
    <div id="latest_threads_link">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="latest_threads_click"><img src="images/kalachi/latest_threads.png" alt="Latest Threads" title="Click Here to see latest threads of this section."></a>
        <table border="0" cellspacing="'.$theme['borderwidth'].'" cellpadding="'.$theme['tablespace'].'" class="tborder" style="display: none;" id="latest_threads_show">
            '.$forum_threads_bit.'
        </table>
    </div>
';
```

### jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('a[id^="latest_threads_click"]').on('click', function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#latest_threads_show').slideToggle();
        $('#latest_threads_click').addClass('latest_threads_link_active');
    });
});
```

### CSS:

```
#latest_threads_link{
    left:0;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:150px;
}

.latest_threads_link_active{
    left:200px;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:150px;
}
```

I want to make it so when `#latest_threads_link` is clicked then `#latest_threads_show` toggleout from left to right and on second click on `#latest_threads_link` then the table `#latest_threads_show` hides.

It actually does with my code but the issue is the `#latest_threads_link` remains on `200px` away from left even on second click. I want `#latest_threads_link` to go `left: 0` on second click.

Please help!!

Comment: can you add your generated html ?then we can test it locally

Comment: `.toggleClass('classname')` is the solution.

Comment: Sad to see none of the answers pointing out `$('#latest_threads_click').slideToggle()` is just `$(this).slideToggle()` and `$('a[id^="latest_threads_click"]')` is faster as just `$('#latest_threads_click')` (assuming there aren't other id's starting with `latest_threads_click`)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you're adding the class on each click. Instead, change this line:

```
$('#latest_threads_click').addClass('latest_threads_link_active');
```

to this:

```
$('#latest_threads_click').toggleClass('latest_threads_link_active');
```

Answer (score 1):

use `toggleClass` :

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/5Y9mG/6/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('a[id^="latest_threads_click"]').on('click', function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#latest_threads_show').slideToggle();
        $('#latest_threads_click').toggleClass('latest_threads_link_active');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$('#latest_threads_show').slideToggle();
```

with

```
$('#latest_threads_show').slideToggle(400, function()
{
    if($(this).is(":hidden"))
    {
        $(this).css({'left':'0px;'});
    }else
    {
        $(this).css({'left':'200px;'});
    }
});
```

It changes the **left** from 0px to 200px and repeat, etc (toggling).